# Combining two async results from MongoDB collection in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm sure this was asked before, but for some reason I am not able to make it work. Started using NodeJS with Mongoose just lately (getting used to doing everything async) 
One of the things I'm trying to achieve is combining two results from two different collections according to some logic.

So assuming I have this get function, it should go fetch asynchronously all skills (for example), then from another collection, i should fetch all specific user skills, and combine them into one set of results, which will add a "isSelected:true" property when it's found in the userSkills collection. This is written in ES6:

```
exports.get = (req, res) => {

const combineSkills = (allSkills)=>{
    const { userid } = req.headers;
     return UserSkills.GetUserSkills(userid).then((response)=>{
        for(var i=0;i<=response.length-1;i++){
           var userSkill = response[i];
           var found = allSkills.filter(e=>e.id==userSkill.skillId);
           if(found.length>0){
                found.isSelected=true;
           }
        }
        return allSkills;
    });
}

const respond = (response) => {
    res.json({
        ReturnCode: 2,
        ReturnObject: response
    })
}

// error occured
const onError = (error) => {
    res.status(403).json({
        ReturnCode: 0,
        ReturnObject: error.message
    })
}

Skills.GetAll()
    .then(combineSkills)
    .then(respond)
    .catch(onError)
```

}

As you can see, I'm trying to call Skills.GetAll() skills, then get results to combineSkills object, do some logic and return the new object. 
I know my problem is in the combineSkills function, where my return statement returns the object before the logic change.

My question is what is the right syntax for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

`filter` function return an array, you have to return the needed skills using `find` method like :

```
  const combineSkills = (allSkills) => {
      const { userid } = req.headers;
      return UserSkills.GetUserSkills(userid).then((response) => {
        for (var i = 0; i <= response.length - 1; i++) {
          var userSkill = response[i];
          var found = allSkills.find(e => e.id == userSkill.skillId);
          if (found) {
            found.isSelected = true;
          }
        }
        return allSkills;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Both works. Find/Filter. Since my collection of "allSkills" is unique. So i'm assuming something/anything is found in order to continue. My problem is with the way Async calls are written, not this logic.

Comment: @Basilf filter won't work unless you do this `found[0].isSelected=true;`

Comment: They can't be, because the combineSkills function returns this func: return UserSkills.GetUserSkills(userid) before it gets to the "Then". this way all of my logic is useless.